# Stop DropShadowBorder console logging

Tags: java, swing, swingx

I have a basic class that extends JButton, and used SwingX's DropShadowBorder to add a simple border. The problem is it displays a time fraction in milliseconds every time I hover the cursor over the button. Is there any way to disable this logging? This is the code I'm using:

```
DropShadowBorder sb = new DropShadowBorder();
sb.paintBorder(this, g2, 25, 15, 625, 525);
```

The output looks like this:

```
1ms
0ms
1ms
1ms
0ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code for DropShadowBorder, I don't see any console output. ( http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Swing-Library/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/border/DropShadowBorder.java.htm)

It must be coming from your button or code.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention I haven't used a single System.out.println in the whole class. Thanks :)

Comment: Might be another class you are using then, the DropShadowBorder looks fine.  Can you create an SSCCE that demonstrates the problem?